# Redux - can't access container properties to pass api credentials (from store) to calling function in container component

Tags: react-redux

Quick Version for people who know the terminology: How do I pass my API Token to my redux actions without passing it in to each presentation component to which I pass (as a prop) the callback functions to dispatch the API calling actions? The API function updates the backend database and then updates the redux store.

I use the connect function and a mapDispatchToProps function, and pass to my presentation component a function that calls an API which modifies the backend database as well as the redux store data. I need to authenticate the user in my api endpoint code. I have an API token which the API code looks up in a db to ensure it is valid and has not expired. These values are passed in when my html is created via a script tag in the html head to make global javascript variables.

I store the apiToken from these global variables in the redux store by an initial dispatch of an action in the container's componentHasMounted function.

It does not feel right to use the global javascript variables to get the apiToken value in the presentation components, as they are meant to be portable.

It does not feel right to pass the apiToken to each and every presentation component as the structure is meant to lessen the number of props passed in to each and every component.

It made sense for me to add the apiToken credentials only back in the Container component - so I put the credentials in the call the markAsComplete function inside the mapDispatchToProps function, adding the auth parameters to the parameter(s) passed from the presentation component back to my container component.

HOWEVER, this did not work as the this.apiToken and this.byUserId are not defined - the 'this' inside the mapDispatchToProps is different to the 'this' of the container component class.

How do others acheieve this?

I have a container function like this:

```

```
class Container extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    var storeState = this.context.store.getState();
    if (storeState && storeState.auth) {
      this.byUserId = storeState.auth.userId;
      this.apiToken = storeState.auth.apiToken;
      this.idOfChosenEntity = globalVarDeclaredInHtmlHeader;
    } else {
      this.byUserId     = false;
      this.apiToken     = false;
      this.idOfChosenEntity = false;
    }
    this.props.dispatch(Actions.fetchDataIntoStoreForChosenEntity(this.byUserId,this.apiToken,this.idOfChosenEntity));
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <DisplayComponent
        chosenEntitysData = {this.props.chosenEntitysData}
        markAsComplete = {this.props.markAsComplete}
      />
    );
  }

}
Container.contextTypes = {
     store: PropTypes.object
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

  return {
    dispatch: dispatch,
    markAsComplete: (idOfChosenEntity) => {
      dispatch(Actions.markAsComplete(this.byUserId,this.apiToken,idOfChosenEntity));
    },
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    chosenEntitysData: state.chosenEntitysData
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps )(Container)
```

```

My backend api is a Laravel PHP app - it authenticates users, generates a random apiToken, stores the apiToken in the users table as users.apiToken with an expiry in users.apiTokenExpiry.

Comment: Where do you think this.byUserId, this.apiToken, this.idOfChosenEntity is defined?

Comment: Is the ComponentDidMount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learnt that mapDispatchToProps has a second parameter 'ownProps'.

Where I have call the ReactDOM.render call I include the global variables like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <UserDetailsContainer
            userIdBy = {userIdBy}
            apiToken = {apiToken}

        />
    </Provider>,
    htmlElement
);
```

The userIdBy and apiToken javascript global variables are defined in a script tag in the head - I am using a blade template served from PHP (Laravel):

```
<script>
  var userIdBy = {{$byUserId}};
  var apiToken = '{{$apiToken}}';
</script>
```

mapDispatchToProps I can refer to these values via the ownProps 2nd optional parameter:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch,ownProps) => {

  return {
    dispatch: dispatch,
    markAsComplete: (idOfChosenEntity) => {
      dispatch(Actions.markAsComplete(ownProps.byUserId,ownProps.apiToken,idOfChosenEntity));
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to just store it in a let or const. Not sure if that will do it or not, but it might fix your issue.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    var storeState = this.context.store.getState();
    if (storeState && storeState.auth) {
      const byUserId = storeState.auth.userId;
      const apiToken = storeState.auth.apiToken;
      const idOfChosenEntity = globalVarDeclaredInHtmlHeader;
    } else {
      const byUserId     = false;
      const apiToken     = false;
      const idOfChosenEntity = false;
    }
    this.props.dispatch(Actions.fetchDataIntoStoreForChosenEntity(byUserId,apiToken, idOfChosenEntity));
  }
```

If it's not a reference issue can you share how your store is structured?